# Set button timeout - to disable for log in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I set the timeout for the button to be disabled immidetaly after it was clicked to avoid people signing up twice?

Currently I have a function below:

```
timeout_init = () => {
     setTimeout("timeout_trigger()", 2000);
  };

<button
  className="button__submit"
  type="submit"
  onClick={this.timeout_init}
 >Submit
</button>
```

How can I add a disabling button into that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React you should use *states* to keep track wether something should be disabled or not.

In example below I use the `isDisabled` state to disable or enable the button. Whenever the button is clicked `setIsDisabled` is set to `true` and therefor the button will now be disabled.

I don't know why you would need a `setTimeout` as you state "..to be disabled immediately after it was clicked..". This does just that.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsDisabled(true);
  };
  
  return (
    <button
      className="button__submit"
      type="submit"
      onClick={handleClick}
      disabled={isDisabled}
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  )
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! but then if someone clicks button will stay disabled even if they clicked and username was not found or password incorrect they will have to change input and click again. How can I set this to automatically enable after that?

Comment: Then you should have some logic that calls `setIsDisabled(false)` whenever you need the button to be enabled again.

Comment: Like after you validated your username and password.

Comment: Like e.g. can I skip the timeout function and just set disabled={isDisabled} and then if there was res from the backend set the button to disabled. Or it would have to be done before the response from the backend?

Comment: The order is like so: Click the button -> Disable the button -> Make validation request -> Check request response -> Enable the button if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The "disabled" state of the button is just that... state.  You'd track it like any other state, for example:

```
// using hooks
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);

// OR if you're using old class-based components
this.state = { isDisabled: false };
```

And use it in the component:

```
<button
  className="button__submit"
  type="submit"
  onClick={this.timeout_init}
  disabled={isDisabled}
>
  Submit
</button>
```

And you can update that state in your click handler:

```
// using hooks
timeout_init = () => {
  setIsDisabled(true);
  setTimeout(timeout_trigger, 2000);
};

// OR if you're using old class-based components
timeout_init = () => {
  this.setState({ isDisabled: true });
  setTimeout(this.timeout_trigger, 2000);
};
```

It's not clear what `timeout_trigger` is, but if that's where you'd want to re-enable the button then you'd `setIsDisabled(false)` in that function as well.

Comment: Thanks! How can it then setIsDisabled(false) to reuse the button? e.g. after button was pressed but username incorrect.

Comment: @mnn: Where in your code do you want to do that?  In the `timeout_trigger` function?  Somewhere else?  Wherever in the logic you want to update the state, that's where you'd update the state.

Answer (score 1):

use the event object to capture the button element then disable it after you call the `setTimeOut(yourCb)`:

```js
const Btn = (props) => {
   const cb =() => {
    console.log("Testing the button")
  }
   const timeout_init = (e) => {
     setTimeout(cb, 2000);
     e.target.disabled = true
  }
  return (
  <button onClick={timeout_init}> Click to disable </button>
)
}

ReactDOM.render(<Btn/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disable a button add a overlay on click on login button.

If the request is failed  remove the overlay so that user can change username/password in the login form.

I the request is success, any how user will be redirected to new page.